# Python not finding kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I have tried many different solutions but always end up with an empty black screen when my program starts up, here is my Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()

input("press Enter to exit")
```

I made quite a basic app just because i wanted to try having external kv files, here is my kv code which is saved as "awesome.kv" with an "All file type":

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Label>
    text: 'Hello World!'
```

This always ends up giving me a black screen when I launch the python file, even though I expect it to have "Hello World!" written.

Please Help!

Comment: what do you mean "All file type"?

Comment: He probably meant that when he saved the kv file, he switched the file extension to "All file type" to explicitly declare its extension

Comment: This looks like it should work, though as in one of the answers you shouldn't normally add the rule for Label (and should instead use your own subclass). What does the output log say about it, is there a message about not finding the file (if it's not clear, paste the log here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use widget's name as your own rule because of [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv). You try to overwrite it and it may have unexpected results. Also, as Leva7 said in his answer + since Kivy 1.really.old a .kv file that is named as class that inherits from App is loaded automatically, you can see it in console. The additional "App" is stripped so e.g. MyApp(App) will look for `my.kv`

Also if you run it with `python main.py -m inspector` and `Ctrl+E`, then you can select any widget available and you'll see that your Label is present. The thing is that you try to overwrite default style and it was probably ignored. Do a custom `Label` like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyLabel(Label): pass    
class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

and in `awesome.kv`

```
<MyLabel>:
    text: 'Hello World'
```

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLabel>:
    text: 'Hello World'
''')

class MyLabel(Label): pass    
class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Comment: This is what I tried(along with the import code too):
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run(). Kivy code: <MyLabel>:
    text: 'Hello World', saved as "my.kv", trying to match the name of the class, although the file either wouldn't start up or had a black screen again. Any suggestions, or do you think it is because i have kivy 1.9.1?

Comment: `#:kivy 1.9.1` is a min. version the file will run with, nothing else. You have either a file like this: `awesome.kv.txt` which you can check if you show knowm extensions or you don't have the file in directory with your `main.py` or you didn't copy it correctly.

Comment: @ KeyWeeUsr Well, all I did was have a file, awesome.kv, saved with an "All type" file extension on my desktop. My python file, awesome.py, is also on my desktop. I'm not sure what you mean by "you don't have the file in directory with your main.py or you didn't copy it correctly."

Comment: @ShadowCoder Win+R, `cmd`, `cd %userprofile%\Desktop`, `dir`, find your file and check the extension i.e. if you see `awesome.kv` or `awesome.kv.txt`

Comment: alternatively try Builder.load_string(''' <paste content of awesome.kv here> ''')

Comment: @ KeyWeeUsr when I put  %userprofile%\Desktop into the cmd, i get this: 'C:\Users\perir\Desktop%' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. although I get my main files when i put in dir.

Comment: ah.. you have to use `cd` command before that to _navigate_ to that folder

Comment: @ KeyWeeUsr and where in the code should i put the " Builder.load_string(''' <paste content of awesome.kv here> ''')"

Comment: Added example to my answer. And posting the log would be nice(it would make things faster) :P

Comment: the thing is, my Python console closes down right after it is starting, even though i try to put  "input("press Enter to exit")"

Comment: What? You run that example and it closes?

Comment: Also, after adding the load.string, my file won't start up. Yes, it closes

Comment: Copy and paste the example(last code box) in my answer to your file or to a separate file, then run it. The code works, problem is how you run it.

Comment: Oh ok, thankfully it did work :), but i might as well stick to putting the code inside of python atm.

Comment: @ KeyWeeUsr 7 Wow, after I strictly copy and pasted the first and second text boxes with an outside kv file, it worked as well!!! I geuss it was my tinkering ith the "input("press Enter to exit")" or that i kept moving the "pass" onto the next line

Comment: Moving `pass` didn't have anything with that. That `input()` maybe :P

Comment: @ KeyWeeUsr Well, thank you very much for the help, now I can get to coding something complex. :)

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by this: "Please don't use widget's name as your own rule because of this". You mean that rules like `<Label>` shouldn't be used? Because I've used them numerous times and never seemed to have a problem with overwriting, my rules just append to the defaults, as it seems

Comment: @Leva7 May append, but that doesn't mean that your properties won't cripple the original design. If you set stuff like color or text and nothing is bounded to that then it may be ok. However if you do more complicated things or even add other widgets to the default one, it may have unexpected results. E.g. if you add a widget to `<ScrollView>` which accepts only one child and you'd want to use that widget more than once, you'd probably lose that widget(because it'd already have a child and may not allow you to add or change it) and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Builder` class to load the kv file with a specific filename
Here is the example usage:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file("awesome.kv")
```

`Builder` also can load the kv instructions from a string, allowing you to have your kv inside the Python code and not in a separate file, using the method `load_string`:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<Label>:
    text: 'Hello World!'
""")
```

You can get a widget as a return value of those methods

```
view = Builder.load_file("awesome.kv")
```

if your kv file returns some widget (looks something like this)

```
Label:
    text: 'Hello World!'
```

The variable `view` will contain a `Label` widget with the text `"Hello World!"`

Also, for me (using Kivy v1.9.2-dev0) your app recognizes the kv file as long as your app class is called `Awesome` or `AwesomeApp`

Comment: I tried both the Builder.load_file and Builder.load_string methods although wasn't having any luck. Most of the time, when I placed the builder.load before i wrote "return Label()", the python file wouldn't even fully start up. Could you please specify where i should put the "from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file("awesome.kv")" because whenever I put it before "return Label()", the file doesnt start up and whenver i put it after "return Label()", it just gives me a blank black screen

Comment: Builder.load_file("alternative_file.kv") doesn't work if you have any "file.kv" that matchs your Appname. Is not totally working and overriding the Builder process :-/ so, remove any kv file that matches your classes before try to load custom named kv files.